# reading into np arrays not working

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

hope all is well...I'm making a dataset feed into `sklearn` algorithms for categorization and couldn't find any easy datasets to start out with so making my own.
got a problem, though...

```
import numpy as np
import random

type_1 = [random.randrange(0, 30, 1) for i in range(50)]
type_1_label = [1 for i in range(50)]

type_2 = [random.randrange(31, 75, 1) for i in range(50)]
type_2_label = [-1 for i in range(50)]

zipped_1 = zip(type_1, type_1_label)
zipped_2 = zip(type_2, type_2_label)

ready = np.array(zipped_1)
print(ready[1])
```

the problem here is that when I zip type one label with type one, the output is an array, of arrays with two indexes, as is expected, and then I need to feed it into a numpy array which returns IndexError: too many indices for array which does not make sense to me; as surely numpy can read a 2x2 array for its N-dimensional array functions? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with the available ones here:http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/index.html#examples-based-on-real-world-datasets?

Comment: Please use [this tool](https://github.com/alexmojaki/askso) to help you write a clearer question. Currently your indentation is a complete mess and we could use a full traceback. Also when I run this code (after fixing the indentation) I get no error.

Comment: Try to explore the awesome dataset repository: https://github.com/caesar0301/awesome-public-datasets and you can also create an account on https://www.kaggle.com/. As @EdChum said you have already a lot of examples embedded with scikit-learn, don't hesitate to look over them.

Comment: Is it possible that you use `print(ready[1])` because you are using Python 3? –

Comment: yes man I am! trying to make the switch now after a clean reinstall of mac osx for other reasons haha, the shift is difficult

Comment: koffee alex hall and edchum ive looked over them and the datasets are just not simple enough at the moment. i am trying to use the knearest neighbours and logistic for a very simple classification problem and theyre all out of the league of where I am right now in my particular textbook. Ive also not programmed before, I only know the maths behind ML as apposed to python itself so dont want to get too complicated right now haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***TL;DR***                 `zipped = list(zip(type_1, type_1_label))`

---

Are you using Python 3? in Python 2 `zip()` returns a list but in Python 3 it returns a *zip object*, and this makes all the difference when you try to put it into a *ndarray*...

```
In [45]: l1 = [1 for i in range(10)]

In [46]: t1 = [randrange(30) for i in range(10)]

In [47]: z1 = zip(t1,l1)

In [48]: z1
Out[48]: <zip at 0x7f3b88044688>

In [49]: a = np.array(z1) ; a
Out[49]: array(<zip object at 0x7f3b88044688>, dtype=object)
```

as you can see, the content of `a` is a single object, ***with no dimensionality***.

What can you do to access the inside object? You can add an additional axis, and then index as usual

```
In [50]: a[None][0]
Out[50]: <zip at 0x7f3b88044688>

In [51]: for t in a[None][0]: print (t)
(6, 1)
(18, 1)
(14, 1)
(27, 1)
(14, 1)
(15, 1)
(10, 1)
(18, 1)
(5, 1)
(9, 1)
```

This is interesting, I hear you saying... but how can I have the old behaviour, when `zip` returned a list and `numpy` was happy with it?

With Python 3 you have to *explicitly* convert to a list,

```
In [52]: z1 = list(zip(t1,l1))

In [53]: a = np.array(z1) ; a
Out[53]: 
array([[ 6,  1],
       [18,  1],
       [14,  1],
       [27,  1],
       [14,  1],
       [15,  1],
       [10,  1],
       [18,  1],
       [ 5,  1],
       [ 9,  1]])
```

and then all it works as usual.

Comment: all of the comments gave me a new insight but this was a good explanation, and is making my transition from 2.7 to 3 much easier, kudos to you

Comment: What I dont understand however, is what the additional axis of a[None][0] does, surely the data should, be in a[1:50]? even if it returns the object instead of ech data point i should be able to access it with for t in ready[0]: print t right?

Comment: @entercaspa A good reply to your legitimate curiosities would exceed the length of a comment — in short, the additional axis lets you have an axis to index (NB you can access an array content only by indexing) and as it happens, creating a _ndarray_ containing a single object and not a sequence of objects doesn't create axes along which to index the content. This is different from your expectations, isn't it? but so it is...  re your last point, I don't understand what is your point... I'd say that it depends on  how you instantiated `ready` but I understand that it's not a satisfactory reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly create the NumPy arrays you want as a result:

```
ready1 = np.random.randint(0, 30, size=(50, 2))
ready1[:, 1] = 1

ready2 = np.random.randint(31, 71, size=(50, 2))
ready2[:, 1] = -1
```

Comment: Im going to start doing this, its much easier thank you g

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your python version and other environment details, but I am guessing that's where the problem is. Your code worked fine for me -

```
import numpy as np
import random
type_1 = [random.randrange(0, 30, 1) for i in range(50)]
type_1_label = [1 for i in range(50)]
type_2 = [random.randrange(31, 75, 1) for i in range(50)]
type_2_label = [-1 for i in range(50)]
zipped = zip(type_1, type_1_label)
zipped_2 = zip(type_2, type_2_label)
ready = np.array(zipped)
print(ready[1])
```

Outputted this...

```
[14  1]
```

I have Python 2.7 Anaconda distribution

Comment: yeah man im on 3.5 or something now, on 2.7 printing it was fine haha